# Change entry/exit text and color in pine script

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to change the entry and exit text and color in pine script?

Currently they are blue for entry and pink for exit.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No but you can add your own labels and hide the built-in labels.

To disable the built-in trade labels on chart, simply go to Settings -> Style and untick the option "Trades on chart".

[image]

See the example below:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

long_color = input.color(color.green, "Long Color")
short_color = input.color(color.red, "Short Color")
text_color = input.color(color.white, "Text Color")

is_new_long = (strategy.position_size > 0) and (strategy.position_size > strategy.position_size[1])
is_new_short = (strategy.position_size < 0) and (strategy.position_size < strategy.position_size[1])

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)

plotshape(is_new_long, "Long", shape.labeldown, location.abovebar, long_color, 0, "Long", text_color)
plotshape(is_new_short, "Short", shape.labelup, location.belowbar, short_color, 0, "Short", text_color)
```

[image]